# WebGL shaders: maximum number of varying variables

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

From the [OpenGL ES spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) section 2.10.4 (Shader Variables: Varying Variables):

> The number of interpolators available for processing varying variables is given by the implementation-dependent constant **`MAX_VARYING_VECTORS`**.
>
> This value represents the number of **four-element floating-point vectors** that can be interpolated; varying variables declared as matrices or arrays will consume multiple interpolators.
>
> When a program is linked, any varying variable written by a vertex shader, or read by a fragment shader, will count against this limit.
>
> A program whose shaders access more than `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` worth of varying variables may fail to link

In Chrome on my machine, `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VARYING_VECTORS)` returns `15`, which means I can use 15 `vec4` varyings in a shader.

I've verified this with a few tests. 15 `vec4` varyings work OK, but when attempting to use 16, the program fails to link and `gl.getProgramInfoLog()` returns `"Varyings over maximum register limit"`.

But how many varyings of type `vec3`, `vec2` or `float` can be used?

The OpenGL ES spec seems to hint at this, without being explicit:

> any varying variable ... will count against this limit.
>
> A program whose shaders access more than `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` ***worth*** of varying variables may fail to link

I'm making two guesses:

1. The maximum number of varying `float`s is given by:
   `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS * 4`
   (4 `float`s per `vec4` vector)
2. If (for example) `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` is `8`, then each of the following can safely be used without causing any linking errors:

   - 8 `vec4` varyings
   - 10 `vec3` varyings
   - 16 `vec2` varyings
   - 32 `float` varyings
   - 3 `vec4`, 3 `vec3`, 3 `vec2` and 5 `float` varyings
   - 1 `vec4` varying array of length `8`
   - 1 `vec3` varying array of length `10`
   - 1 `vec2` varying array of length `16`
   - 1 `float` varying array of length `32`
   - Any other combination of `vec4` / `vec3` / `vec2` / `float` variables or arrays, which uses a maximum of 32 `float`s

So with my `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` value of `15`, I guess I can use a maximum of 60 `float`s.
My tests seem to confirm this.
For example, 30 `vec2` varyings work OK on my machine, but 31 causes a `"Varyings over maximum register limit"` linking error.

So my questions are:

- Are my two guesses correct?
- If `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` is `8`, then is it safe to use 16 `vec2` varyings? Is this guaranteed to always work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the WebGL spec

> 6.24 Packing Restrictions for Uniforms and Varyings
>
> The OpenGL ES Shading Language, Version 1.00 [GLES20GLSL], Appendix A, Section 7 "Counting of Varyings and Uniforms" defines a conservative algorithm for computing the storage required for all of the uniform and varying variables in a shader. The GLSL ES specification requires that if the packing algorithm defined in Appendix A succeeds, then the shader must succeed compilation on the target platform. The WebGL API further requires that if the packing algorithm fails either for the uniform variables of a shader or for the varying variables of a program, compilation or linking must fail.

So yes, if you read the algorithm if `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` is 8 you can use 16 `vec2`s. You can not however use 10 `vec3`s. You could only use 8 `vec3`s

There are also array restrictions. For example you couldn't have an array of `float`s larger than 8 nor an array of `vec2` larger than 8 if `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` is 8.

Comment: Many thanks. The description of the packing algorithm is very helpful, especially: *"The target architecture consists of a grid of registers, `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` rows by 4 columns for varying variables. Each register can contain a `float` value. No splitting of variables is permitted. Vectors always occupy registers in a single row."* That explains why 10 `vec3`s are not allowed. *"Elements of an array must be in different rows."* So an array can't have more than `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` elements.

Comment: This point seems important to be aware of too: *"If referenced in the fragment shader (after preprocessing), the built-in special variables (`gl_FragCoord`, `gl_FrontFacing` and `gl_PointCoord`) are included when calculating the storage requirements of varyings."*

Comment: @TachyonVortex I know this is a somewhat old post, but it seems like the array restrictions do not always apply. On Firefox on my Mac machine, `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VARYING_VECTORS)` returns 16, yet I am able to use a 32-element `vec2` array. However, on Chrome, my `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` is 31, and the browser refuses to link the program, saying `Varyings over maximum register limit`. I need a varying `vec2` array of around 50 elements, and I'm wondering how I can achieve that.

Comment: This looks like a bug in firefox 36. [The conformance test](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/glsl/misc/shader-uniform-packing-restrictions.html?webglVersion=1) fails for me on my Mac. Checking [FirefoxNightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) (FF 39) it seems to be fixed. Maybe you should try it and see if your program starts having the same behavior as Chrome.  As for needing 50 vec2s it sounds like you're S.O.L. If `MAX_VARYING_VECTORS` is 16 the most vec2s you could possibly have is 32.

Comment: Oddly enough, my program still functions with 50 vec2s in both firefox and nightly. Hooray for me, but not so great in terms of conformance.

Comment: I know this is old but for people reading this thread, if you want a random access array of values in a shader you should probably be [using a texture](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-gpgpu.html), not a uniform array.