# Does WebGL have a uniform or texture binding limit?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm trying to render a car's license plate in WebGL with a purple texture whose uniform name is `diffTex`.

1. When I render the rest of the car with a simple black material and no textures, the drawcall that renders the license plate binds uniform 35 to `diffTex` and uniform 36 to `specNrmMap` for 6 total [`activeTexture()` calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/activeTexture). The purple plate shows onscreen as expected.

[image]

2. However, when I render the entire car with their own materials, textures, etc. the drawcall that renders the license plate skips `diffTex`, and binds uniform 35 to `specNrmMap` with no #36 for 5 total `activeTexture()` calls. The purple plate shows up white without the diffuse texture.

[image]

Does WebGL have a uniform limit or a texture binding limit that I might be overlooking? webglreport.com states my Max Texture Image Units is 16 in the fragment shader, and I'm only using 6, so I have 10 to spare. I'm not changing anything in the license plate material, it just works when I render the car in black without textures, and it stops working when I render the rest of the car with textures.

Answer (score 3):

Uniforms do not have numbers in WebGL. Those numbers in your debugger are something assigned by the debugger. How it numbers them is up to the debugger. It could number them by querying them. If so they'd get different numbers across implementations. They'd also change if you change the shader. It could number them based on the order you use them. If so, then you setting different textures would also number them different.

Uniforms are almost always optimized out if they are not used so if you stopped using a particular uniform then again the debugger you're using might number them differently.

As for limits, as you already checked there is a limit to the number of texture units and you can bind a different texture to every unit so your 6 textures is well under the limit.

For uniforms the limit is queried via `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS)` for vertex shaders and `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS)` though it's unlikely you're hitting that limit because you'd get an error trying to compile the shaders.

Note: how many uniforms you can actually use from that number is defined by the packing algorithm. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26683122/128511)

As for why your code is not working you'd have to post a repo (in the question itself) for us to figure that out.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the uniforms could be assigned in different order in the debugger, but the `diffTex` uniform is nowhere to be found in the second screenshot. You can also see in the center, the [`activeTexture` command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/activeTexture) only goes up to TEXTURE4, instead of reaching TEXTURE5. Anyway, I'll try to reproduce this with in simpler demo to see if I can get to the bottom of it.